# doing jQuery logic foreach button of table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a companies-table having the following columns: `id`, `company_name`, `select_button`.

When the `select_button` of a company-row is clicked I want:

1. the button of this row to become disabled and
2. I want it to alert the company name of this row.

I don't know how to get this done under the circumstance when each button refers to a certain row with a certain id.
Can someone give me advice please how to get started here?

Do I give each button an id? If yes How do I? My following logic does not work:

```
<input type='button' class="button_<?php echo $company->id ?>" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':button_<?php echo $company->id ?>').click(function(){
            alert('<?php echo $company->company_name; ?>');
            $(':button_<?php echo $company->id ?>').prop("disabled",true);             
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type='button' class="button"  value="<?php echo $company->id ?>"/>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);             
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to save data on an HTML element and retrieve it later:

```
<input type="button" class="my-btn" id="button_1" value="button #1" />
<input type="button" class="my-btn" id="button_2" value="button #2" />
<input type="button" class="my-btn" id="button_3" value="button #3" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_1').data('msg', 'text you need to alert for button #1');   
    $('#button_2').data('msg', 'text you need to alert for button #2');
    $('#button_3').data('msg', 'text you need to alert for button #3');

    $('.my-btn').on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).data('msg'));
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);             
    });
});
```

Note: you probably need to change the above to `id="button_<?php echo $company->id ?>" value="button #<?php echo $company->id ?>"`

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEbfA/).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers. Yeah I am still stuck as when I do $('#button_').click(f...) without the php then I get it to alert a simple 'something' but when I add the php-code inside '$('#button_<?php echo $company->id ?>').click(f...) it does not alert a simple 'something' - I did change input id in html accordingly both times.